# Filter results using custom buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a menu that filters results based on a custom button that I made (which is just clickable text). Does anyone know of a way to create a filter results menu with custom buttons instead of check-boxes? Any help would be amazing!

I found this example of filtering results using check-boxes:

[JSfiddle of filter results using check-boxes](http://jsfiddle.net/YEtgM/17/)

As an example, I've included my own button into the formatting of the check-box example.

```js
<script>
var Lst;
function changecolor(obj) {
  if (Lst) Lst.style.color = "#663399";
  obj.style.color = "red";
  Lst = obj;
}
</script>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0724fb;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" onclick="changecolor(this)">
  <li>1 bedroom</li>
</a>

<a href="#" onclick="changecolor(this)">
  <li>2 bedrooms</li>
</a>

<a href="#" onclick="changecolor(this)">
  <li>3 bedrooms</li>
</a>
<br>

<a href="#" onclick="changecolor(this)">
  <li>london</li>
</a>

<a href="#" onclick="changecolor(this)">
  <li>new york</li>
</a>

<a href="#" onclick="changecolor(this)">
  <li>paris</li>
</a>
<br>

<ul>
  1 bedroom apartment paris
  <br>1 bedroom apartment
  <br>3 bedroom apartment london
  <br>2 bedroom apartment new york
  <br>2 bedroom apartment paris
  <br>2 bedroom apartment london
  <br>3 bedroom apartment new york
  <br>1 bedroom apartment london
  <br>2 bedroom apartment new york
</ul>
```

Comment: You could try using a select dropdown http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: This could work, but my aim is to use the text buttons that I created.

Comment: What buttons are you refering to? The `a`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the checkbox example you provided, I just updated the code to instead use classes which you toggle on selected items, thus allowing you to style them as you please.

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bdum8euw/1/

```
$('section').click(function(e) {

    var room_array = new Array(),
        loc_array = new Array();
    $('.br').each(function() {

        if (this == e.target) {
                $(this).toggleClass('is-checked');
                //console.log(e.target);
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('is-checked')) {
            room_array.push($(this).data('bedrooms'));
        }
    });

    $('.loc').each(function() {
        if (this == e.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('is-checked');
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('is-checked')) {
            loc_array.push($(this).data('location'));
        }
    });

    $('li').each(function() {

        if (($.inArray($(this).data('location'), loc_array) > -1 || !$('.loc.is-checked').length) && ($.inArray($(this).data('bedrooms'), room_array) > -1 || !$('.br.is-checked').length)) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});

<section>
  <a data-bedrooms="1" class="br" type="checkbox">1 bedroom</a>
  <a data-bedrooms="2" class="br" type="checkbox">2 bedrooms</a>
  <a data-bedrooms="3" class="br" type="checkbox">3 bedrooms</a><br>

  <a data-location="london" class="loc" type="checkbox">london</a>
  <a data-location="new-york" class="loc" type="checkbox">new york</a>
  <a data-location="paris" class="loc" type="checkbox">paris</a>
</section>

<ul>
    <li data-bedrooms="1"  data-location="paris">1 bedroom apartment paris</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="1" data-location="paris">1 bedroom apartment</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="3" data-location="london">3 bedroom apartment london</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="2" data-location="new-york">2 bedroom apartment new york</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="2" data-location="paris">2 bedroom apartment paris</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="2" data-location="london">2 bedroom apartment london</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="3" data-location="new-york">3 bedroom apartment new yourk</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="1" data-location="london">1 bedroom apartment london</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="2" data-location="new-york">2 bedroom apartment new yor</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for. The only issue is that  the hand icon doesn't appear when hovering over the text and the rollover to blue is missing. But it should be quite easy to put this back in. Thanks so much!